# Expo/React Native: Play back sound effects with low latency?

Tags: react-native, audio, expo

I'm working on a game using Expo/React Native. I need to play back sound effects with as low latency as possible. For button presses and such.

For now I've tried it using [`expo-av`](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/audio/). It works, but the latency is too high. Below is my implementation (trying to only load audio once, and then replay it).

```
function DetailsScreen() {
  const [sound, setSound] = useState<Audio.Sound>();

  async function playSound() {
    if (!sound) return;

    await sound.replayAsync();
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadSound = async () => {
      const { sound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(
        require('assets/sounds/Tink.aiff')
      );
      setSound(sound);
    };
    loadSound();

    return sound
      ? () => {
        sound.unloadAsync();
      }
      : undefined;
  }, [sound, setSound]);

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Details Screen</Text>
      <Button title="Play sound" onPress={playSound} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

When I develop natively for iOS I've used the [`AudioServicesPlaySystemSound`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/audiotoolbox/1405248-audioservicesplaysystemsound) API to play sound effects with very low latency. Is there any wrapper for this API for React Native? Or other ways to reduce latency?

Comment: Did you figured out something ?

Comment: @ScreamZ Unfortunately no. Not working on the project anymore, but as far as I know, it's not possible without creating a custom plugin.